# How do prevent a memory leak inside my endless while loop in C#

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I am developing a plugin for an application.
The application is calling the plugin when it loads and the plugin start and endless look in this form:

```cs
const int sleepTime = 60 * 1000;

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        //vaProxy.WriteToLog("Invoking checker...", "Green");
        
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> SessionState = vaProxy.SessionState;
        Dictionary<string, CallBack> callBacks = vaProxy.SessionState["CallBacks"];

        //Checks will only occur in the Pit
        if (!Config.IsProcessRunning("Falcon BMS")) continue;
        var isJoystickProfileLoaded = vaProxy.GetBoolean("isJoystickProfileLoaded");
        bool isProfileLoaded = isJoystickProfileLoaded == true;
        if (ConfigFile.IsTrue(vaProxy, "EnableJoystickLoaded") &&
            !vaProxy.SessionState["JanJanJoystickIsLoaded"] && !isProfileLoaded)
        {
            Config.SaySomething("Verify Joystick profile is loaded");
        }

        if (!SharedMem.GetStatus("isFlying")) continue;
        if (ConfigFile.GetEntry(vaProxy, "AutoAVTR") == "True" &&
            !SharedMem.GetStatus("isOnGround"))
        {
            //Check AVTR status
            if (!SharedMem.GetStatus("AVTR"))
            {
                callBacks["SimAVTRSwitchOn"]
                    .Press(vaProxy, sayWhat: "Start recording", waitAfter: 500);
            }
        }

        if (SessionState.ContainsKey("JanJanIsAutoSave") && !SharedMem.GetStatus("isOnGround"))
        {
            if (vaProxy.SessionState["JanJanIsAutoSave"])
            {
                //vaProxy.WriteToLog("Checking save time", "Green");
                //save game...
                GameIO.SaveGame(vaProxy);
            }
        }


        if (!SessionState.ContainsKey("JanJanIsStatusReport")) continue;
        if (vaProxy.SessionState["JanJanIsStatusReport"])
        {
            Sim.MyStatus(vaProxy);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        vaProxy.WriteToLog("Dynamic Checks\n" + ex.Message, "Red");
        Console.Beep();
    }
}
```

`vaProxy` is a dynamic variable controlled by the sending application.

I suspect that this endless loop is causing a memory leak.
How can I prevent this?
Should I use the using() statement and if yes how?
I can convert the "DO SOME STUFF" to a class, will that help?

Comment: if you want to keep running your console application forever, then you can create a windows service,

Comment: i'd rather use a proper method from within my current code

Comment: "I suspect that this endless loop is causing a memory leak." Is that just a guess, or do you have evidence? Please give us more details - including what's happening in "do some stuff". The loop *on its own* isn't going to introduce a memory leak.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here. I think the problem code is `DO SOME STUFF`.

Comment: i added the DO STUFF part. it calls other methods though which i did not include

Comment: Really curious why a plug-in would need to run an endless loop. To me a plug-in is just a bunch of functions the main program calls when it wants something done

Comment: normally this is what the plugin does however. It's a plugin for a voice recognition software which  handles the 'cockpit' of a flight sim.
I want to run dynamic checks every N minutes, therefore I run these endless loops.
How else can I perform a check every N minutes?

Comment: So what makes you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: You need to test what exactly causes the memory leak. There are tools helping you to do that.  Normally C# will do garbage collection automatically and release memory you no longer need. You should specifically watch any function that extend a data structure. I would suspect your WriteToLog function and anything similar. It also may be that functions you call but you did not create yourself cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a function not created by be which did not dispose of itself properly.
Placing it in a `using(){...}` block solved it.